# A word for something that is currently relevant

Tags: single-word-requests

I feel like there is a word on the tip of my tongue for something that is particularly relevant in the current climate but I can't quite get it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: In BrE, 'umbrella'. Seriously, 'big thing', usually in 'the next big thing', is often used informally for something considered important / fashionable at a certain time by the masses.

Comment: It's ***topical*** - and climate *change* is literally becoming a ***hot topic***.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the word you are looking for is: *topical*?

As per [Cambridge Dictionary:
topical adjective (HAPPENING NOW)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/topical):
of interest at the present time; relating to things that are happening at present.

Comment: Welcome. This answer would greatly improved if you could provide context on why you think it is correct. A good way to start is a dictionary definition.

Comment: Up-voted pending a link to reference.

Answer (score 1):

**germane**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/germane)

> Related to a matter at hand, especially to a subject under discussion

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***apropos***:

> Very appropriate to a particular situation.
>   ‘*the composer's reference to child's play is **apropos***’
>   ‘*the song feels **apropos** to a midnight jaunt*’
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apropos)</sub>

Or ***pertinent***:

> Relevant or applicable to a particular matter; apposite.
>   ‘she asked me a lot of very ***pertinent*** questions’
>   ‘practitioners must consider all factors ***pertinent*** to a situation’
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pertinent)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

English borrows words and phrases from other languages quite extensively, and so as well as the existing excellent suggestions of *"topical"* and *"germane"*, I would add the borrowed French phrase ***"au courant"*** which is accepted in English useage in all relevant dictionaries, and adds an implication of literal *currency in cultural context*.

From Merriam-Webster
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/au%20courant)

> Definition:
>   1
>       a : fully informed : up-to-date
>       b : fashionable, stylish au courant outfits
>       2 : fully familiar : conversant

So you might say, for example: *"I try to stay ***au courant*** in the architectural facade world"*.

Comment: References are good but you **must** properly attribute them (i.e. mention the name/link of the source and use blockquote format for the quote).

Answer (score 0):

#### In Vogue

> **Adj**. in the current fashion or style

([Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+vogue))

E.g.
*Feminism is really **in vogue**, what with the Me Too movement.*